# Local JavaScript Function to Format SQL queries like SQLFormat.org performs without the web call?

Tags: javascript, sql, format

Currently, I can format my SQL queries programmatically by making `POST` request to the http://sqlformat.org/api/v1/format API; but there is a limitation of 500 request can be served per hour from the single IP as mentioned here http://sqlformat.org/api/#usage.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a local `Javascript` or other mechanism available in by which I can achieve the same result as obtained from the SQLFormat.org website locally without going to the web?

Answer (score 3):

There is a javascript library to do that
https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sql-formatter

Usage:

```js
import sqlFormatter from "sql-formatter";
console.log(sqlFormatter.format("SELECT * FROM table1"));
```

This will output:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sql-formater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-formatter) from npm:

```
npm install sql-formatter
```

then

```
import { format } from 'sql-formatter';

console.log(format('SELECT * FROM tbl', { language: 'mysql' }));
```